# How to convert a file with rows of different length to single column, adding the first word of the row to a separate column

Tags: linux

I have a file "foo.txt" that is formatted as follows:

```
chr1 11160 12411
chr2 9068719 9068893 9069194
```

Note that each row has a different number of fields. I would like to convert it to look like this:

```
chr1 11160
chr1 12411
chr2 9068719
chr2 9068893
chr2 9069194
```

Where the file is now 2 columns, and the first word in each row is now the first column

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) printf $1 " %s\n",$i}' dk_tmp.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterating over the fields, printing the first field every time.

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s %s\n",$1, $i}' foo.txt
chr1 11160
chr1 12411
chr2 9068719
chr2 9068893
chr2 9069194
```